# Mysql query to compare weekly data for the last 3 years side by side

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help to create mysql statement. I have sales table which records daily sals data.
Now, I want to compare weekly sales for the last 3 years side by side by week number.

> Here is the example data in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa26aa/10).

And this is what I have tried so far but is returning only one week's data:

```
SELECT  YEARWEEK(s1.sale_date,1) AS weekY1, SUM(s1.total) AS totalY1, 
                    YEARWEEK(s2.sale_date,1) AS weekY2, SUM(s2.total) AS totalY2,
                    YEARWEEK(s3.sale_date,1) AS weekY3, SUM(s3.total) AS totalY3
            from sales_chc s1
            LEFT JOIN sales_chc s2
            ON s2.sale_date = (s1.sale_date -INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
            LEFT JOIN sales_chc s3
            ON s3.sale_date = (s1.sale_date -INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
            WHERE YEAR(s1.sale_date) = '2017' AND YEARWEEK(s1.sale_date, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)-1
            GROUP BY YEARWEEK(s1.sale_date, 1)
```

Comment: What's your expected result based on your sample data?

Comment: I want all the weeks (till date) listed with their total sale amounts for each year.

Comment: Your GROUP BY looks a little suspicious, and isn't your WHERE clause limiting it to YEARWEEKs that are **equal** to the current YEARWEEK (minus 1, which I'm not sure is valid)?

Comment: With the updates, I think you just need to lose the WHERE clause which is limiting it to the current week.  

Note that there is still a more subtle issue:  If there is data for 2016-01-01 (in s2) but not 2017-01-01 (in s1), then it will ignore 2016-01-01 because it's only checking for things that exist in s1.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that the WHERE was intended to limit s1 to only the last year, I think you want simply `WHERE s1.sale_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)`.  You probably also want to tack an `ORDER BY 1` onto the end to make sure your weeks are in order.

Comment: Seeing as you're outputting to PHP anyway, I think your whole approach is wrong. Just pivot the output of a standard query using a PHP loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(s1.sale_date) as WEEKNUM, 
SUM(case when YEAR(s1.sale_date) = '2017' then  s1.total else 0 end) AS total2017,
SUM(case when YEAR(s1.sale_date) = '2016' then s1.total else 0 end) AS total2016, 
SUM(case when YEAR(s1.sale_date) = '2015' then s1.total else 0 end) AS total2015 
from sales_chc s1
GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(s1.sale_date)
```